# Random Forest in Pose Estimation

Tags: random-forest

I am having problem in understanding the number of feature input to the Random forest mentioned in the paper below.

[Shotton, Jamie, et al. "Efficient human pose estimation from single depth images." Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, IEEE Transactions on 35.12 (2013): 2821-2840.](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/papers/pose-from-depth-pami.pdf)

It says,

- feature parameters $\phi = (\delta_1, \delta_2)$
- feature response: $f(u|\phi) = z(u + \delta_{1}/z(u)) - z(u + \delta_{2}/z(u))$

Does it mean there are total 5 input features (5 dimension) for the training and testing of Random Forest: $\delta_{1}x, \delta_{1}y, \delta_{2}x, \delta_{2}y, f$?

Answer (score 0):

After a careful study of the paper, it seems the feature is only one dimension, which is the feature response: $f(u|\phi) = z(u + \delta_{1}/z(u)) - z(u + \delta_{2}/z(u))$.